# Accelerometer TimeStamp

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to get the time at the point when I get the values from the accelerometer. The value that I am getting at the momentis "55112312109395" which I do not understand.

The syntax I am using to get the value is event.timestamp and when looking on android developer website it should give the value in nanosecond.

I will be obliged if someone can help with this question cause it is driving me crazy

Thank you, 
Safiul

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to read up on epochs. Time is relative you know :)

Comment: epochs?? what is that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to convert the nanosecond timestamp to readable time?
If yes, maybe you can try:

```
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;  

    public static void timeConvert() {

        long eventTimeNano = 55112312109395L;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss_SSS");
        long timeInMillis = (new Date()).getTime() 
            + (eventTimeNano - System.nanoTime()) / 1000000L;
        Date eventTimedate = new Date(timeInMillis);

        String eventTime = dateFormat.format(eventTimedate);
        System.out.println(eventTime);
     }
```

This `eventTime` should be in format, e.g. `2015-08-15-00_49_30_281`.